# ExtJS default filter active but grid isn't filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have an `ExtJS 4.1.3` grid with a defaulted filter option selected but when the grid loads all of the grid items are showing up. Is there a better way to define a default option?

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

**Code**

```
{
  text: 'Status',
  width: 100,
  dataIndex: 'TopicStateValue',
  filter: {
           active: true,
           type: 'list',
           value: 'Open/Current',
           options: ['Open/Current', 'Archived/Closed', 'Hold']
            }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure is there a "filter" option in the Column configuration? Based on Sencha docs (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) Ext.grid.column.Column has not "filter" configuration value.

Comment: @overlordhammer the filters work in the fiddle

Comment: You are right, it's not part of a normal column configuration value but a config value used by Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the source code, and the **filter object is not being created**  **until** the first time the **header menu is triggered** (lazy feature instantiation), this means that your configuration options are not being applied until the first time the menu is rendered, and also means that is not possible to trigger an update manually before that time since the reference to the column feature only contains a configuration object at the time. You can see in [this forked version](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24bn) of your code that the ***init*** method (which is called to setup the filter) is called only after the column has been clicked. You can further customize the init method on Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature component to create the filters earlier and apply them. Maybe you can try to apply the filters to the store instead?

I hope this answer can point you in the right direction to solve your problem.